# Eagle - How to make the router ignore internally connected pins (the other way around)

Tags: eaglecad, autorouter

I have a push-button component in Eagle 8.2.1. The same kind of thing as described in this question:
[Eagle - How to make the router ignore internally connected pins (in a package)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/110585/eagle-how-to-make-the-router-ignore-internally-connected-pins-in-a-package)
Contrary to the person in that question, I want the autorouter ignore the fact that these pins could be used as a bridge and have it connect **all** traces to one of them.

The setting in the "Connect" window allows me to get one of the following two options:

1. Force traces to go to both pins:
   [image: Connect Connected]
   [image: Connected]
2. Consider the pins to be connected the same way as if they were connected by a trace that's not part of the autorouter:
   [image: Connect Unconnected]
   [image: Unconnected]

I want neither of those. I want the autorouter to connect all traces to one single pin (ideally whichever works best for the situation):
[image: Ideal 1]
[image: Ideal 2]

How can I accomplish this? I can't seem to find an option for this.
PS: Ideally I would like the airwires to also behave this way. If there's a way for that too, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to have it automatically decide which pin is the best for a given situation.

What you can do to approximate the behaviour you desire is to modify the part such that only one of the internally connected pads is assigned to the symbol pin (the other is left as unconnected). In this way all traces will connect to the same pad.

Comment: Meh. That'll make building a components even more cumbersome than it already is. And **I** don't even know which one's the best option. Is there any way I can at least tell it to use a specific one without having to mangle the library?